# calculating r squared but says y_orig is not defined

Tags: python, linear-regression

I'm trying to calculate R-squared using a tutorial on-line (I'm a very slow beginner!) and have come across an error stating that y_orig is not defined. I'm using the code supplied but linking to a spreadsheet whereas the tutorial has created his own np.array, so I think this is the issue. I think I have to create a variable for y_orig and possibly y_line, anyone out there willing to help? Code below.

```
import statistics
from statistics import mean
import numpy as np
Damodaran = pd.read_c("C://Users//Darren//Desktop//CFA//Strathclyde//Big     Data//Assignment//Latest//revised 2.csv")
xs = Damodaran.Growth
ys = Damodaran.Beta
plt.scatter(xs,ys)
plt.show()
def best_fit_slope (xs,ys): 
    m =( ((mean(xs)*mean(ys))-mean(xs*ys))/
    ((mean(xs)*mean(xs))-mean(xs*xs)) )
return m
m = best_fit_slope(xs,ys)
print(m)

from matplotlib import style
style.use('fivethirtyeight')
def best_fit_slope_and_intercept (xs,ys): 
    m =( ((mean(xs)*mean(ys))-mean(xs*ys))/
    ((mean(xs)*mean(xs))-mean(xs*xs)) )
    b = mean(ys) - m*mean(xs)
return m, b

def squared_error (ys_orig, ys_line):
    return sum((ys_line - ys_orig)**2)

def coeffiecient_of_determination (ys_orig, ys_line):
    y_mean_line= [mean(ys_orig) for ys in y_orig]
    squared_error_regr = squared_error (ys_orig, ys_line)
    squared_error_y_mean = squared_error(ys_orig, y_mean_line)
    return 1 - (squared_error_regr / squared_error_y_mean)

m,b = best_fit_slope_and_intercept(xs,ys)
```

Thanks Coeur, why change a few months later....?

Answer (score 0):

The error says that because while `ys_orig` is defined, `y_orig` is not.

Comment: Thanks Scott, not sure how to define y, i'll go back to the r-squared formula and re-read. Cheers, Darren.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot format code in a comment, and so place it here. Here is an example Python graphing polynomial fitter that also calculates RMSE and R-squared fit statistics.

```
import numpy, matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

xData = numpy.array([1.1, 2.2, 3.3, 4.4, 5.0, 6.6, 7.7, 0.0])
yData = numpy.array([1.1, 20.2, 30.3, 40.4, 50.0, 60.6, 70.7, 0.1])

polynomialOrder = 2 # example quadratic

# curve fit the test data
fittedParameters = numpy.polyfit(xData, yData, polynomialOrder)
print('Fitted Parameters:', fittedParameters)

modelPredictions = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, xData)
absError = modelPredictions - yData

SE = numpy.square(absError) # squared errors
MSE = numpy.mean(SE) # mean squared errors
RMSE = numpy.sqrt(MSE) # Root Mean Squared Error, RMSE
Rsquared = 1.0 - (numpy.var(absError) / numpy.var(yData))
print('RMSE:', RMSE)
print('R-squared:', Rsquared)

print()


##########################################################
# graphics output section
def ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight):
    f = plt.figure(figsize=(graphWidth/100.0, graphHeight/100.0), dpi=100)
    axes = f.add_subplot(111)

    # first the raw data as a scatter plot
    axes.plot(xData, yData,  'D')

    # create data for the fitted equation plot
    xModel = numpy.linspace(min(xData), max(xData))
    yModel = numpy.polyval(fittedParameters, xModel)

    # now the model as a line plot
    axes.plot(xModel, yModel)

    axes.set_xlabel('X Data') # X axis data label
    axes.set_ylabel('Y Data') # Y axis data label

    plt.show()
    plt.close('all') # clean up after using pyplot

graphWidth = 800
graphHeight = 600
ModelAndScatterPlot(graphWidth, graphHeight)
```

Comment: Wow thanks James, different level! I'll read up on polynomial fitting rather than my original approach, appreciate it! Cheers, Darren.

Comment: I also have a somewhat similar non-linear fitting example, if that might be helpful. Sometimes you need to fit non-linear equations, so that could be handy later.

Comment: By the way, if you use "polynomialOrder = 7" you can see a particularly nasty-looking example of overfitting. A seventh-order polynomial really stinks on this data.